# Higher dimensional polar coordinates

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

Suppose I have a $2n-1$ dimensional region in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and a function which are both particularly nice when written in polar coordinates $(r_1,\theta_1,r_2,\theta_2,\cdots,r_n,\theta_n)$: the region is defined by $\sum a_i\theta_i=c$ and the function by $\prod r_i^{b_i}$. I'm struggling to figure out what volume form I need to put on this region to correctly compute the integral.

For the $n=1$ case, things are sort of too easy to give me any idea of what's going on- the problem's an integral along a line. The next case, $n=2$, involves an integral over some 3-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, which I find it extremely hard to visualize and see what the correct volume form is- I know I should have some factor of $r_1$ and maybe of $r_2$ to account for some of the rotation I can make in the region- this leads me to make the guess that the general answer should be something like $r_1r_2\cdots r_{n-1} dr_1\cdots dr_n d\theta_1\cdots d\theta_{n-1}$, but I'm kind of lost right now and would appreciate some course correction if you could give it.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is right. Represent your equation for the region (possibly after renumbering the coordinates) as
$$
\theta_n=t_0+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_j\theta_j.
$$
Consider the coordinates $(r_1,\theta_1,\dotsc,r_{n-1},\theta_{n-1},r_n,t)$ on  $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, where
$$
 t=\theta_n-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_j\theta_j.
$$

The volume form on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is 
$$
dvol=r_1\dots r_{n-1}r_n dr_1\dotsm dr_{n-1}dr_n d\theta_1\dotsm d\theta_{n-1}d\theta_n\\=\bigl(r_1\dots r_{n-1} dr_1\dotsm dr_{n-1}dr_n d\theta_1\dotsm d\theta_{n-1}\bigr)\bigl(r_ndt\bigr).
$$
Now the second factor, $r_ndt$, is the arc length along the circle orthogonal to your region $\{t=t_0\}$, and hence the first factor is teh volume form on the region itself.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thank you for your answer. One thing that sort of bugged be about my guess was that it wasn't symmetric in the indicies- I don't see how you should get the same answer depending on which coordinate you replace with $t$. If, for example, $n=2$ and I pick $a_1=a_2=1, c=0, b_1=1, b_2=3$, and integrate over the region where $0\leq r_i\leq 1$ it seems like the answer I get should depend on whether I pick $t=\theta_1$ or $t=\theta_2$. Can you help me sort this out?